# How to transfer exceptions between layers?

Tags: c#, exception, design-patterns, dto, using-statement

I have a project divided in 3 layers. In the Business Logic Layer, are two classes that read and write a CSV file. In a `using` statement, I need to handle the `IOException` and I find that I can do that with DTO and "send" to UI Layer the problem description, but I don't know how. You can explain me, please? Or maybe is another good way to transfer the information between layers.

The write method:

```
public void WriteCustomers(string filePath, IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter);
                csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CustomerMap>();
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(customers);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {

        }
    }
```

**An approach of the solution:**

```
public void WriteCustomers(string filePath, IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
                throw new IOException("The output file path is not valid.");
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter);
                csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CustomerMap>();
                csvWriter.WriteRecords(customers);
            }
        }
```

Comment: An error will bubble up the stack from where you call it so if you are just looking to get information about the error rather than resolve it this will pass up the layers naturally,

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to verify if the path is correct, and IOException will be thrown if is's not correct so I can't create another class to deal with that.

Comment: I'm not really talking about creating another class, you will be able to see an error from this procedure in another procedure calling it (which can be in a different layer). Might be easiest if I try an explain it in an answer where I can use code formatting i guess

Comment: Yes, it's true, but I want to particularize the message every class. You can explain what you want to say in an answer.

Comment: You can alter what is in the error and still pass that up the stack, You could also have some error trapping e.g. check that filepath is valid and if not throw an error (which will then also pass up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of an error will naturally bubble up to the UI layer where you are calling it from, so you can catch and handle the error by displaying a message there. Below is a pseudo code example which might help explain what I mean:

```
namespace My.UiLayer
{
    public class MyUiClass
    {
        try
        {
            BusinessLogicClass blc = new BusinessLogicClass();
            blc.WriteCustomers(string filePath, IEnumerable<Customer> customers);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
          // Read from 'e' and display description in your UI here
        }
    }
}
```

*Note you may want to change the above to catch all Exceptions with `Exception`, rather than just `IOException` in the above, depending on what you may want to display to the user*

If you want specific message from different procedures classes then you could do something like the following:

```
public void WriteCustomers(string filePath, IEnumerable<Customer> customers)
    {
        try
        {
           // Code
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new IOException("Error in write customers", ex);
        }
    }


public void WriteSomethingElse(string filePath, IEnumerable<Something> s)
    {
        try
        {
           // Code
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new IOException("Error in something else", ex);
        }
    }
```

And these will be caught in the calling UI layer with the message you have specified. There are a variety of ways you may want to capture/handle the errors but the key point is that the error will pass up the layer; you don't need a data transfer object (DTO) to send that information.

Comment: Thank you! This is the approach that I was looking for. I edited the post.